# Can one field in a composite key be dependent on the other?

Tags: sql, composite-key

I am thinking about making a composite key for a table of mine (which would be composed of two fields, fields A and B). However, field B is dependent on field A. Would this composite key violate any database design principles?

Comment: Dependent? You mean B is computed from A in some way, or do you mean something else? A computed column can be used as a key, FYI.

Comment: This might be a situation where a surrogate primary key, such as an identity column, might be preferable.

Comment: This is just an example, but here is a situation similar to mine. Let's say you have an automaker column and a car model column. The database would look have the following columns (automaker, model). Since there are many car models that belong to the same automaker, both automaker and model would have to be combined in order for there to be unique indexes. models are dependent on the manufacturer, so it fits with the A and B pattern of my original post. A table structured like this (surrogate_prime, automaker, model) would not be suitable, (continued in next comment)

Comment: as model would still be dependent on automaker, which is not the primary key.

Comment: If models are unique, meaning that two different brands cannot have the same model, then model should be your primary key, and make should be a foreign key that references an automaker table.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes.  It does violate database design principles.  Why not just use `A`?  That is, you can always look up the value of `B` using a `JOIN`, so a composite foreign key reference is unnecessary.  Storing the value of `B` in referring tables is redundant and inefficient (takes up space in both data pages and index pages).

There are some cases where such a foreign key *is* useful.  You have not provided enough information to know if you have such a case.  So, as a general design principle this doesn't sound right.  There may be exceptions, so it is not always a bad idea.

Comment: It's possible for B to be dependent on A as well as C, D, etc. In this scenario, A may not be sufficient to be a unique primary key by itself, and would require something like B (which depends on A along with other dependencies) to form a unique composite primary key. I think this sort of thing is not entirely unreasonable.